# MySQL INSERT shorthand vs longhand performance

Tags: mysql, database, performance, query-performance, insert-into

What is the difference between:

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` SET `col1` = 'val1', `col2` = 'val2', `col3` = 'val3'
```

and

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`) VALUES('val1','val2','val3')
```

Is there a performance benefit of using shorthand? I prefer longhand myself, but logically, for performance reasons, should I be using shorthand every time? Benchmark testing is telling me that option #2 above is a bit faster by a margin of about 3%, but why?

```
public function benchmarkInsert() {

    $int_value = 1;
    $varchar_value = 'Stuff';
    $serialized_value = json_encode(array('Serialized Stuff'));

    $this->db->query("TRUNCATE TABLE `query_benchmark`");

    $start = microtime(true);       

    for ( $i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++ ) {          
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `query_benchmark` (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`) VALUES($int_value,'$varchar_value','$serialized_value')");
    }       

    $elapsed = microtime(true) - $start;

    echo 'SHORTHAND: '.$elapsed.'<br/>';

    $this->db->query("TRUNCATE TABLE `query_benchmark`");       

    $start = microtime(true);       

    for ( $i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++ ) {

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `query_benchmark` SET `col1` = $int_value, `col2` = '$varchar_value', `col3` = '$serialized_value'");

    }       

    $elapsed = microtime(true) - $start;

    echo 'LONGHAND: '.$elapsed.'<br/>';

}
```

Comment: If you insert 100 rows in a single `INSERT` statement, you will get about a 10-fold improvement.  Perhaps 1000% is better than 3%?  (It requires a variant of the second syntax.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be a difference in those two queries. They should be transformed to the same execution plan by the database.

The 3% difference is probably being caused unrelated factor (caching, database load, etc)

You can validate this by viewing the execution plan with `EXPLAIN`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html

Comment: or some slight difference in the parser logic path.

Comment: Must be the caching. When I switch the shorthand & longhand, the differential is essentially the same but flip-flopped.

Comment: @FurryWombat Maybe. 3% is such a small margin that it could be explained by many different things.

Answer (score 1):

the difference is 2. #1 is longer than #2 by 2 characters.

i tested it in Notepad.

over time we are talking carpal tunnel syndrome

also give your left pinky a break with the `

Comment: Ha, Drew, you're talking to a pianist. Ring finger hits it without skipping a beat. But thanks for the thought :)